# Remove link around logo

Tags: headers, logo

I have this in the functions.php:

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', array(
        'height'      => 200,
        'width'       => 1000,
        'flex-width'  => true,
        'flex-height' => true,
    ) );
```

and this in my header file:

```
<div class="site-branding">
        <?php
        the_custom_logo();
        if ( is_front_page() || is_home() ) : ?>
            <h1 class="site-title"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></h1>
        <?php else : ?>
            <p class="site-title"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></p>
        <?php
        endif;

        $description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
        if ( $description || is_customize_preview() ) : ?>
            <p class="site-description"><?php echo $description; /* WPCS: xss ok. */ ?></p>
        <?php
        endif; ?>
    </div>
```

The logo links to my home page, and I don't know why. What's causing it to do that? There's no a tag surrounding it. How can I make the logo NOT a link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_custom_logo/) for `the_custom_logo()`:

> Displays a custom logo, linked to home.

So it's doing what it's supposed to.

If you want to do anything other than that, you can get the ID of the logo image using `get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' )`. Then you can do whatever you want to it, such as just outputting the image:

```
echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' ), 'full' )
```

Comment: I figured that the_custom_logo() was doing what it was supposed to, I just needed to know how to make it not do what it's supposed to =]

So are you saying I should replace the_custom_logo() in my header file with echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' ), 'full' ) ?

Comment: I did what I just asked and it worked! Thank you very much Jacob!